# ListView hidden behind button

Tags: android

The contents of my list view get hidden behind the button as follows:

[image]

**The xml file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="top"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"     
/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    > 

     <Button 
        android:text="Send" 
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addItems"
       >
    </Button>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/message" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </EditText>                
 </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**The TextView for each row is as follows:**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="20sp"
 />
```

What should i do to align it properly (as in above the button)?
Also when the listView is with just one or two entries, and when the keyboard is opened to type, the whole view shifts? How do I fix that as well? Thanks in advance

Comment: try adding `android:layout_above="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"` to your `ListView`

Comment: You are using RelativeLayout, so you need to set the position of it's childs.
See [Positioning Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Position)

Comment: I tried positioning, but it still comes behind the button. I want it to come just above the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaned up and corected the code a bit. Perhaps this is what you were looking for. Let me know if it works. Cheers !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="addItems"
            android:text="Send" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/InnerRelativeLayout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

adding `android:layout_above="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"` to your `ListView`.

**RelativeLayout** has child views specify their position relative to the parent view or to each other (specified by ID). So you can align two elements by right border, or make one below another, centered in the screen, centered left, and so on. By default, all child views are drawn at the top-left of the layout, so you must define the position of each view using the various layout properties available from **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams**.

For put your `InnerRelativeLayout` layout at Top add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to your `InnerRelativeLayout` and remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

**Update:** set up your **Layout** like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/Beige "
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="addItems"
        android:text="Send" >
    </Button>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button"
        android:hint="Enter text" >
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: The button shifts to the top of the activity.  I tried various relative layouts but nothing is working as I want it to.

Comment: @user3368396 tell me what you want?

Comment: @user3368396 see my update and set u your layout on that way.

Comment: Thanks but i need the edit text and the button to appear at the bottom of the screen. when i click add item, I need to append at the end of the list and i want it to stay above my button.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_above="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"` in your listview

Comment: That worked kinda. Now my first text appears just above the button. Is there a way to make it appear at the top of the page regardless of the keyboard being opened or closed?

Answer (score 0):

Make the outer `RelativeLayout` into a `LinearLayout` with orientation vertical.  Then, for the `ListView` set layout_height as 0dp and layout_weight as 1.  The `ListView` will fill up all the remaining space in the `LinearLayout` without overlapping other views.

Also, stop using `fill_parent`, it's been deprecated and you should use `match_parent` instead.